# Run time error '-2147188160 (80048240)': Application (unknown member) : Invalid request. sub or function not defined

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I am getting this error while trying to run the following macro.
The error shows up on the first(!) time the "AddSlide" is executed and only then(!). The macro continues (after I click on "End" in the message box) and works well without any error message after that.

```
Sub PushChartsToPPT_1()

    Dim ppt As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim pptPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim pptSld As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim pptShp As PowerPoint.Shape
    Dim EndTime As Single

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cht As Chart
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i, j As Single
    Dim MainWorkBook, tempWorkBook As Workbook
    Dim tempSheet As Worksheet
    Dim pptCL As CustomLayout
    Dim myShape As Object
    Dim DestinationPPT, str As String


    Set MainWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook

    'Get the PowerPoint Application object:
    Set ppt = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    DestinationPPT = "Template.pptx"
    Set pptPres = ppt.Presentations.Open(DestinationPPT, True) ' read only

    'Get a Custom Layout:
    For Each pptCL In pptPres.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts
       If pptCL.Name = "Title and Content" Then Exit For
    Next pptCL

    ppt.Visible = msoTrue


    For Each ws In MainWorkBook.Worksheets
        For i = 1 To ws.ChartObjects.Count
            '>>>>> error next line
            Set pptSld = pptPres.Slides.AddSlide(pptPres.Slides.Count + 1, pptCL) '>>>>>error on this line
            pptSld.Select


            Set cht = ws.ChartObjects(i).Chart
            cht.ChartArea.Copy
            DoEvents
            pptSld.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteMetafilePicture).Select

        Next i
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: According to the comment in the code the Presentation is being opened **Read-only**. But then you try adding a slide to it, which can't be done with a read-only file?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the previous loop is finishing, instead of doing an Exit For at a 'title and content' slide?   That would mean that the value pptCL is undefined.   However, that would be the wrong error report; that line run with pptCL undefined causes an "invalid procedure call or argument".

But the odd thing is that your code died for me right on the line where the powerpoint file is opened, the line:

> > Set pptPres = ppt.Presentations.Open(DestinationPPT, True) ' read only

...and it died with that exact "automation error".  I compared to code I have where a powerpoint file opened fine, and that code had the line:

> > ppt.Visible = msoTrue

...making the powerpoint application visible, just above the "open" command.  When I added that line to your code, the error went away, in my run.

This may be a complete red herring, but since it worked for me, and since you aren't getting any other answers, take a moment and try it.