# VBA: Opening a PowerPoint Presentation from Excel: Error "Method 'Open' of object 'Presentations' failed."

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

**edit2:** I think I identified the problem: Another user had the file open, but when I manually opened it he must have had it closed. Now I wonder how to avoid this issue because I don't the macro to fail, much less so with some cryptic error message. I would be happy with read-only, but apparently it doesn't give me that option. Do I have to open every file read-only by default to not run into this issue again?

I've been working on some code and all of a sudden, a very basic line gets me an error message: "Run time error -2147467529 (80004005): Method 'Open' of object 'Presentations' failed. I recreated the problem in this piece of code:

```
Dim PowerPointApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim myPresentation As PowerPoint.Presentation

Sub MReport()

    Dim DestinationTemplate As String, DestinationAmp As String
    Dim PPAmp As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim AmpName As String, PathAmp As String

    DestinationTemplate = "G:\MReport\MReportTemplate.pptm"
    PathAmp = "G:\MReport\Amp\MReportAmp\"
    AmpName = Dir(PathAmp & "Amp*long*.*")

    DestinationAmp = PathAmp & AmpName
    Debug.Print DestinationAmp

    Set PowerPointApp = New PowerPoint.Application
    Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Open(DestinationTemplate) 'works
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'doesn't help
    Set PPAmp = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Open(DestinationAmp) '<-- error
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

The error occurs in the line `Set PPAmp = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Open(DestinationAmp)`. It worked literally dozens of times before. Then I rearranged some code unrelated to this PowerPoint file and shifted it into separate procedures and the error happened. The error now happens in the new, re-arranged file and in the old one, which successfully ran for days.

I tried restarting my computer, MS PowerPoint 16.0 Object Library is also checked. The `Debug.Print` statement gives me the correct path, I can copy it into the file explorer and the right presentation opens.

The code is written in Excel, but when I copied it into PowerPoint I got the same error. I also tried declaring all the PowerPoint-related variables (`PowerPointApp`, `myPresentation`, `PPAmp`) as `Object` and then use `Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")` without success.

**edit:** Typing PowerPointApp.Presentations.Open("Filepath") gives me the same error (I think): "Run time error '-2147467259 (80004005)': Automation error. Unknown error."

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53992743/run-time-error-2147188160-80048240-application-unknown-member-invalid may be relevant (i.e. try making `PowerPointApp` visible before opening the file)?

Comment: I notice that the first file is a "*.pptm" file - is PowerPoint waiting for you to respond about whether or not to enable macros?  You may need to add your G: drive to the Trusted Folders.  (Literally just try opening them in the other order.  And, you can probably delete those `DisplayAlerts` lines too)

Comment: See if the `TestFileOpened` procedure in this support article helps. The article mentions Excel, but the procedure should also work for PowerPoint since it's not application-specific.